# How do I get text to appear over a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good morning. I am currently working on a final project for my Unix class and it trying to implement some of the stuff learnt through building a web game. One feature that I want to incorporate is the ability to add text over a div as shown in the picture. How would I go about that?

[image: image of result]

Comment: Hello, welcome. Its important that when you create a question that you add your source code as we cannot help otherwise. Also be careful when making questions because too many bad ones will get you banned from questions until you can prove you are still of use to the site.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As pavel mentioned, Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service. Show what you have and what you've tried. Otherwise it will be difficult for us to answer your questions. Edit your question to add these details. Also [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help on writing good questions. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try including some of your own source code next time, just so we get an idea of what you're having issues with.

But to put text over, try using `position: relative`, inside a div with a background image of what you want.

Eg.

```css
.parent {
       background-image:url("https://picsum.photos/200/300");
       width: 800px;
       height: 800px;
    }

.text {
      position: relative;
      top: 20px;
      left: 40px; /*edit top, left, right, and bottom to change position*/
      
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
      <div class="parent">
        <p class="text">TEXT!</p>
      </div>
    </body>
```

If you can't use a background image, try using absolute positioning.
Here's a great tutorial for that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6UgYq3J3Qs